# Select distinct value if only ONE distinct value exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using `SQL Server 2012`. I want to select a distinct value from a table `T` if only **one** distinct value exists. Below I have a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

This data would result in 1 returned value: 'bbb'

```
ID    Data
----------
1    'bbb'
```

The same goes for this data:

```
ID    Data
----------
1    'bbb'
2    'bbb'
3    'bbb'
```

But this data would result in 0 returned rows:

```
ID    Data
----------
1    'aaa'
2    'bbb'
3    'bbb'
```

Ideally, there would be a way to count the number of rows in the `WHERE` clause (without grouping data). Also, please remember that my original query is quite complicated. For this simplified version, I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT [Data] FROM
    (SELECT [Data], COUNT(*) OVER() AS [DinstinctValueCount] FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT [Data] FROM [T]) [A]) [B] WHERE [DistinctValueCount] = 1
```

Invalid column name 'DistinctValueCount'.

### UPDATE

I found a solution. Is there a better one?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MIN([Data]) ELSE NULL END AS [Data] FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT [Data] FROM [T]) [A]
```

Any aggregate function will do.

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if i am wrong because i want to know have misunderstood something ??

Comment: Same logic works in Postgres. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), [Data]
FROM [tablename]
GROUP BY [Data]
HAVING
  1=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Data]) FROM [tablename])
```

or if you don't want to repeat [tablename], you could use something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), MIN([Data])
FROM [tablename]
HAVING MIN([Data])=MAX([Data])
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba8c7/4).

Comment: Yes. The only problem is that `tablename` is repeated, so for a very complex query representing `tablename` I would need to duplicate the query or use a temporary table variable. No?

Comment: @l33t i've updated my answer, second solution should be what you are looking for...

Comment: Very interesting MIN/MAX hack! If you compare it with the `CASE WHEN` solution in my update, which one do you believe will be faster?

Comment: @l33t the case when is also a nice idea, it will return a null column instead of 0 rows but you could change it to `SELECT MIN([A].[Data]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Data] FROM [tablename]) [A] HAVING COUNT(*)=1`, i am not sure which one is faster... maybe the min/max one? but i'm not sure, i would do some tests....

Comment: +1 for the `HAVING MIN(Data) = MAX(Data)`. Simple and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Where clause logically execute before select statement. So the alias which mentioned in select list is not found in where clause because select would execute next.
true is this :

```
with s as (
     SELECT [Data] FROM
        (SELECT [Data], COUNT(*) OVER() AS [DinstinctValueCount] FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT [Data] FROM [T]) [A]) [B] )
     SELECT * FROM S WHERE  [DinstinctValueCount]= 1
```

Comment: "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tbl t1
JOIN ( 
  SELECT data
  FROM tbl t2
  GROUP BY data
  HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl)
) t2 ON t2.data = t1.data
```

Comment: This returns three rows for the second dataset.

Comment: I thought you wanted three rows? If you only ever want one or zero then you should just be able use the inner query.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The only problem is that `tbl` is repeated, so for a very complex query representing `tbl` I would need to duplicate the query or use a temporary table variable. No?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong here but I think following will do

```
Select Data from T Group by Data having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: To summarize; `a` => result is `a`. `b`,`b` => result is `b`. However, `a`,`b` => result is empty. *Two* distinct values does not qualify!

Comment: ok sorry i think i did not get the question and so i have written i might be wrong because the person with such high reputation will have this answer easily .. i will delete the post after sometime .. and now i read that you did not wish to group the data .. so i am compltely wrong here